# HDMI goes into motherboard or graphics card?

Tags: hdmi, gpu

This is probably obvious but I'm new to this. I've got a new HDMI monitor, which I'll be using with my new build.

Some motherboards say 'HDMI'  on them, but so do graphics cards. This seems sort of confusing. I'll be getting a HD 7850 but I'm not sure about which motherboard yet.

Do I need to make sure I buy a HDMI motherboard or is it just the GPU I should be looking out for?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The HDMI/DVI/VGA connectors on the motherboard will be for using "integrated" graphics chips which would either be built into the CPU of as a part of the motherboard itself.

If you are going to be buying a dedicated graphics card then you will want to use the HDMI port on that graphics card and completely ignore any ports on the motherboard.

Note that if you get a graphics card with DVI rather than HDMI you can get [adaptors](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dvi%20to%20hdmi) that can do the conversion as HDMI and DVI share a (nearly) identical interface for pushing data at the display.

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking just for a 7850 with HDMI out. You do want to use a 7850, so only that graphic card is important for you.

HDMI out for mainboards just means, that the on-board graphics can output via HDMI, no need for that as you are using the far better 7850 for your graphics.